# Why doesn't my ternary if statement evaluate for NULL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ternary-operator

I am trying to change the text of an appended button based on the value returned from the database via `Ajax` function.

```
 .append($('<td>').attr('id', "tdBookingStatus" + i).html(val.HasCustomerArrived === true ? "Checked in" : (val.HasCustomerArrived == null) ? " ": "Cancelled"))
```

But it doesn't work for NULL even though the function is returning NULL but it doesn't work I tried `==` and `===` and `!` but nothing works.

Comment: f val.HasCustomerArrived is "null" (String) then you can try like this .append($('<td>').attr('id', "tdBookingStatus" + i).html(val.HasCustomerArrived ? "Checked in" : (val.HasCustomerArrived == "null") ? " ": "Cancelled"));

Comment: .html(val.HasCustomerArrived === true , looks like you missed a closing paranthesis here

Comment: I think we need more context. When I try like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsvb9skb/2/), it works as expected for the values true, false and null.

Comment: Oh, and you say the function returns `NULL`, but your code checks for `null`. That might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to check for `=== ''` if you are considering that value. Using `null` for that will not work.

```js
//for blank value
var test = '';
var res = test === true ? "Checked in" : (test === null || test === '') ? " ": "Cancelled"

console.log(res);

//for null value
var test = null;
var res = test === true ? "Checked in" : (test === null || test === '') ? " ": "Cancelled"

console.log(res);

//for true value
var test = true;
var res = test === true ? "Checked in" : (test === null || test === '') ? " ": "Cancelled"
console.log(res);

//for false value
var test = false;
var res = test === true ? "Checked in" : (test === null || test === '') ? " ": "Cancelled"
console.log(res);
```

Comment: what if val.HasCustomerArrived is "null" (String)

Comment: Where does OP mentioned that is a string value ? @thaveethugce

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal thanks, it works for the '' part but not for the FALSE part, if val.HasCustomerArrived === false then it should say cancelled.

Comment: @Stacky use strict comparison `===` check my updated answer

Comment: @Stacky let me know if there is still any confusion.